# Prevent client app of Azure CosmosDB from create new database

Tags: mongodb, azure, nosql, cloud

We have a solution running in Azure which has a CosmosDB account as well. Unfortunately sometimes we use bad database names, but CosmosDB creates new databases in that cases instead of refusing connection causing extra expenses.

Do you guys have any this how we can prevent CosmosDB from doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by bad database name?

Comment: The actual database is called "jeez", but if I have "jeez-other" in my config, a new "jeez-other" is being created with non-shared 1000 RU scale.

Comment: Are you creating a database in your code where you read the name of the database from config file?

Comment: Exactly, names are read from configuration.